# How to solve this exception while running smart GraphHopper?

Tags: graphhopper

When I run the GraphHopper main project:

This is the output:

```
strs = [config=../config.properties, maps/dublin-m50.osm]
2016-08-02 18:13:43,335 [main] WARN  graphhopper.util.Helper - Skipping configuration at line: default location for cache is used /tmp/srtm
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to specify an OSM file.
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.init(GraphHopper.java:483)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.main(GraphHopper.java:57)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.337s
Finished at: Tue Aug 02 18:13:43 EET 2016
Final Memory: 7M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default-cli) on project graphhopper: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Note that I already added dublin-m50.osm to maps folder as stated in the readme file.

I also have a question I am using the latest Maven 3.3.9, this would cause a problem ?

Comment: We now know what the output is ... but what did you try exactly? Did you start GraphHopper from a java process or via command line? And which command exactly?

Comment: Please refrain from ASAP begging here, this [is normally a cause for downvoting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).